# Multiple fixed-width columns don't fit side-by-side

Tags: html, css

I'm reading through an HTML/CSS book and trying to place multiple `div` elements side-by-side via `float`, each with a fixed width and margin so that they fit perfectly into the page width. Even boiling down the book's example to its most simple form, the last column is always bumped down as though the containing element wasn't big enough. Any insight?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        width: 960px;
      }
      #c1, #c2, #c3 {
        float: left;
        width: 300px;
        height: 50px;
        margin: 10px;
        border: 1px dashed black;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="c1">
      </div>
      <div id="c2">
      </div>
      <div id="c3">
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1otbf659/

Comment: the border takes space! https://jsfiddle.net/1otbf659/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have border, and your divs not `300px`. Your divs are `302px`.
Just add `box-sizing: border-box` to your divs.

```
 #c1, #c2, #c3 {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Here is [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Narek_T/1otbf659/3/)

Comment: or shrink the width by 2px

Comment: Gosh, so simple! Didn't realize the border was included in the size. Thank you!